# Is this an established design pattern?

Tags: java, design-patterns

I am writing a game in Java, in which each `Entity` can have a list of attached `EntityComponents`. For example, `Entities` that can be killed (such as the `Player`) will have a `Health` component. Checking the Player's health looks like this:

```
int health = ((Health) player.getComponent(Health.KEY)).getValue();
```

I came up with a slight shortcut, where every `EntityComponent` contains a static `get` method that calls an Entity's `getComponent` method with the appropriate key. Checking the Player's health now looks like this:

```
int health = Health.of(player).getValue();
```

Is this an established design pattern? If so, which is it? Does it seem like a good idea (essentially an added method call for slightly shorter code)? Is there, perhaps, a better way to achieve what I'm trying to do?

**EDIT**

Some clarification, here...

- `Health` contains methods such as `getValue`, `setValue`, `modValue`, `isDead`.
- `Health.of(entity)` just calls `entity.getComponent(KEY)`, where `KEY` is a field in the `Health` class.
- `Health.of` and `Health.getValue` were previously called `Health.get` and `Health.getHealth`, respectively, but were changed based on comments.
- Not every `Entity` is killable - that is, not every `Entity` will
  have health. So adding a `getHealth` method to every `Entity` will
  not work.
- A `Killable` interface containing a `getHealth` method is also not
  ideal, because that would require every killable `Entity` to
  duplicate the same health-related code.
- Thus, the choice of having a separate `Health` component is a
  deliberate one in order to extract all shared code to a common
  location.
- Extending from a common base class, e.g. `KillableEntity` is also not a viable solution, because `Health` is one of many possible components, and it would be impractical (perhaps even impossible) to define an inheritance structure that accommodates all possible combinations.

Comment: Can you clue us in a bit about the implementation in both cases?  How will `Health.get()` look up a given player?

Comment: What is the concept of your ``EntityComponents``? Why can't you just provide a method ``player.getHealth()``? Anything else seems like extra clutter, judging based on the information you provided so far.

Comment: What exectly are the benefits of this "component" architecture compared with simple composition? It sounds to me like if you had implemented mere class fields using some weird roundabout.

Comment: Though I understand the meaning, I immediately see one thing: cyclic dependencies. Player may depend on Health which depends on Player.

Comment: Shorter code but more difficult to understand. Shorter is not better. (and I'm curious to see what you have in Health)

Comment: @Fundhor I can only imagine `public class Health { public static final String KEY = "health"; private int health; public int getHealth() { return health; } public Health get(Player player) { return player.getComponent(KEY); }}` By the way, SonarQube would qualify Health.health as bad practice.

Comment: I have edited the question to include the reasoning behind the component architecture, some extra details about the implementation, and a few possible improvements to my original implementation based on some of the answers / comments here.

Answer (score 1):

Is this an established design pattern? No. I would describe it as an anti-pattern rather.

```
int health = Health.get(player).getHealth();
```

Here you are asking Health to get the player and then asking the player to get its health, which could lead to confusion.

From what I understand it seems that you are favouring composition over inheritance. Given that, something like this would probably make more sense,

```
int health = player.getComponentIntValue(Health.KEY);
```

You could also consider letting player implement a HasHealth interface instead which would reduce to :

```
int health = player.getHealth();
```

Comment: Perhaps the method is badly named - how about `Health.of(player)`? An interface is something I have considered but it would require all killable Entities to duplicate the same health-related code, which is why I favoured a separate Health component.

Comment: That would be slightly better, but you would still be asking a class of the property of an object, to inspect the object itself. What would happen if one of your entities needed to store health in a different way? Some options would be to use inheritance and create a KillableEntity base class. Another would be to use a default method implementation in the interface, if you are using java 8 of course. Failing this, I would go for the getComponentIntValue method.

Comment: Entities that need to store `Health` in a different way can just override the `Health` class to provide a different implementation, and the pattern still works. The problem with a `KillableEntity` base class is that the `Health` component is just one of many possible components; it would be impossible to define an inheritance structure that accommodates all possible combinations. The `getComponentIntValue` similarly falls down when you consider other components that aren't based around a single integer value. I think my original implementation may be the better alternative here.

Comment: First: that Approach is called "Fluent Programming", it is not really a pattern. Second, I like the "Health.of(player)" construct. However I would omit the "getValue()" method and simply let the "of()" method grab and return the value. Consider to use a more "oo" language, e.g. Python or Groovy, then you have dynamic typing and dynamic method dispatch and don't have to think about inapprobriated inheritance hierarchies.

Comment: @Dan the Entity base class would need to supply many more methods if different return values are required. I would argue that since you would need to know what value to expect, this would not make a difference.

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer, but I think it will be useful.

---

Consider using `default` methods to provide direct access to the members of `Health`:

```
public interface HealthComponent extends Health {

    Health healthComponent();

    default int currentHealth() {
        this.healthComponent().currentHealth();
    }
}
```

Now if `Player` implements `Health`, `HealthComponent` and the `healthComponent` method, you can do:

```
Player player = new Player();

player.currentHealth();
```

It's much more succinct. This pattern simulates Scala's [traits](http://www.scala-lang.org/old/node/126).

---

Some clarification:

```
public interface Health {

    int currentHealth();

    void adjustHealth(int amount);

    boolean isDead();
}


public final class DefaultHealth implements Health {

    private int currentHealth;

    public DefaultHealth(final int startingHealth) {

        super();

        currentHealth = startingHealth;
    }

    public int currentHealth() {

        return currentHealth;
    }

    public void adjustHealth(final int amount) {

        if (isDead()) {

            return;
        }

        currentHealth += amount;

        if (currentHealth < 0) {

            currentHealth = 0;
        }
    }

    public boolean isDead() {

        return currentHealth > 0;
    }
}

public class Player implements HealthComponent {

    private final Health health;

    public Player(final Health health) {

        super();

        this.health = health;
    }

    public Health healthComponent() {

        return health;
    }
}
```

---

*Disclaimer: this code was written in the browser; it may not compile.*

Comment: I think this idea has some potential, but I'm not sure about this sentence: "Now if Player implements Health, HealthComponent and the healthComponent method"; Health is a class, not an interface, so it cannot be implemented - sorry if this was unclear. I assume you mean instead that the Player should have an attached Health component. Also, rather than requiring the Player to implement a healthComponent() method, the `currentHealth` method could just call `this.getComponent(Health.KEY)` as this is a mechanism that already exists.

Comment: My setup would assume: `Health` is an interface with various health releated methods, such as `currentHealth`; `Health` would have a concrete implementation, such as `DefaultHealth`; `HealthComponent` is a convenience interface to allow objects to expose the methods of `Health` using an internal `Health` instance. You could use a generic container to fetch the `Health` instance, as you suggest.

Answer (score 0):

You can do direct no need to add player.getComponent method, if u dnt have any specific reason behind getComponent method.

```
int health = player.getHealth(Health.KEY);
```

Player is the parent enitity and player has health component so getHealth method shoul be on player object not somethin like this

```
    int health = Health.get(player).getHealth();
```

Comment: Don't use code formatting for text that isn't code.

Comment: Well ... Correct in saying to have a `getHealth` method in the `Player` class. But does it still need a parameter?

Comment: I think it depend on the method if there are multiple health reports then it needs a parameter otherwise there is no need of parameter, thanks @Seelenvirtuose

Comment: Hmmm ... It was a rhetorical question. There is no use in having a `getHealth` method that needs an argument called `Health.KEY`. In fact, this is a dangerous duplicate code!

Comment: This will require every killable Entity to implement the same getHealth, setHealth, modHealth, etc. methods. Extracting this common code to a shared component was an intentional decision.

Answer (score 0):

For this problem it seems enough for me to do one off the following solution :

1. derive Player class from Entity and implement getHealth() method for Entity class
2. make Entity an interface which requires the getHealth() method and implement the method in the Player class which in this case implements the Entity interface.

Comment: Not every Entity will have a health value - take a projectile, for example. I will clarify the question.

Comment: sometimes it is simplier to have parameter even if they are not used, so you can use more generic objets. You can always give a heath of 1 to your projectile and never use it in your code.

Comment: The `Health` component is one of many possible components. If I added unused fields / methods to all Entities for all components, it could bloat them out quite significantly.

Comment: This is the wrong approach as now every Thing that is an Entity has a getHealth method even if it actually has no health. How do you distinguish between a dead player and a rock?

Answer (score 0):

It's just like:

> get player's health, or get the health of the player

Personally I like first way. using static method is likely better for methods with primitive parameters without an englobing context (like a funcion in procedural paradigm, for ex: `Math.abs(int x)`).

In your case health is a property of a player

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't it be easier to have 3 classes ?

```
public abstract class Person {

}
public class Mortal extends Person {
    //int health; 
    //setHealth(); getHealth{}; modHealth{}; 
    //mortal(int health)
}
public class Immortal extends Person {}
```

And then, simply,

```
Person mortalPlayer = new Mortal(100);
mortalPlayer.getHealth();
```

Comment: The problem is that Health is one of many possible components; it would be impractical (perhaps even impossible) to define an inheritance structure that accommodates all possible combinations. For example, what if I also wanted to add a Speed component to some entities? Then I would need MoveableMortal, ImmoveableMortal, MoveableImmortal, ImmoveableImmortal, etc. You get the idea.

Comment: Got it ! My solution was way too simple you're right. Then your first solution is the best, do not care too much about length of lines as long as it is easy to read.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like overengineering to me.

```
player.getComponent(Health.KEY)).getValue();
```

What is the meaning of `component`? It is most likely some artificial concept which should not belong to player. Player has health. Player does not have component.

---

Most likely simplest solution with

```
player.getHealth();
```

will be better.

Comment: Please see my edit in the question / my other comments. The component system is very intentional - in the case of the Health component, it's because not every Entity has health, so I attach the component only to those that need it.